# jquery: how to add event handler to dynamically added element without adding it to existing element again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll try to explain my problem: 
I have a website where the user dynamically adds elements. They all belong to the "toBuy" class. Whenever a new element is added to this class I need to attach a click-handler to only this element but not to all others. To keep my code clean I want to have a function that does this work. Here is what i've tried:

this is how the stuff is added:

```
$("#addItemButton").click(function(){
            var item= $('#item').val();
            $('#item').val("");
            var quantity= $('#quantity').val();
            $('#quantity').val("");
            var comment=$('#addComment').val();
            $('#addComment').val("");
            //construct new html
            var newitem="<div class='toBuyItem'><div class='item'>";
            newitem+=item;
            newitem+="</div><div class='quantity'>";
            newitem+=quantity; 
            newitem+="</div><div class='comment'><img src='img/comment";
            if(comment==""){
                newitem+="_none"
            }
            newitem+=".png' alt='Comment'></div><div class='itemComment'>"
            newitem+=comment;
            newitem+="</div></div>";

            $("#toBuyItems" ).prepend( newitem );
            toggle("#addItemClicked");
            initializeEventListeners();
        });
```

then this is the initializeEventListeners function (which I also run when the page loads so that the existing elements have the event handlers already:

```
function initializeEventListeners(){
        $(".toBuyItem").click(function(){
            console.log($(this).html());
            console.log($(this).has('.itemComment').length);
            if($(this).has('.itemComment').length != 0){
                console.log("toggling");
                $(this).addClass("toggling");
                toggle(".toggling .itemComment");
                $(this).removeClass("toggling");
            }          
        });
    }
function toggle(item){

        $( item ).slideToggle(500);
    }
```

now apparently what happens is that when a new element is added the existing elements get a new event handler for clicking (so they have it twice). Meaning that they toggle on and off with just one click. Probably it's damn simple but I cannot wrap my head around it....

EDIT:
so this works:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toBuyItem', function(){
    if($(this).has('.itemComment').length != 0){
        console.log("toggling");
        $(this).addClass("toggling");
        toggle(".toggling .itemComment");
        $(this).removeClass("toggling");
    } 


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery's `on` method. This way you have to add `event` only once. This will be added automatically to dynamically added elements.

```
$(document/parentSelector).on('click', '.toBuyItem', function() {
    // Event handler code here
});
```

If you are using `parentSelector` in the above syntax, it has to be present at the time of adding event.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: thanks. edited the comments around so that it doesn't get confusing if anybody ever looks at it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). It can attach handlers to all existing in the DOM and created in future tags of the selector. Syntax is as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toBuyItem', function(){
//do onClick stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you can delegate click handling to `document` or some suitable container element, and that's probably what I would do.

But you could alternatively define a *named* click handler, which would be available to be attached to elements already present on page load, and (scope permitting) to elements added later.

You might choose to write ...

```
function buy() {
    if($(this).has('.itemComment').length != 0) {
        $(this).addClass("toggling");
        toggle(".toggling .itemComment");
        $(this).removeClass("toggling");
    }
}
function initializeEventListeners() {
    $(".toBuyItem").on('click', buy);
}
$("#addItemButton").on('click', function() {
    var item = $('#item').val(),
        quantity = $('#quantity').val(),
        comment = $('#addComment').val();
    $('#item', '#quantity', '#addComment').val("");
    //construct and append a new item
    var $newitem = $('<div class="toBuyItem"><div class="item">' + item + '</div><div class="quantity">' + quantity + '</div><div class="comment"><img alt="Comment"></div><div class="itemComment">' + comment + '</div></div>').prependTo("#toBuyItems").on('click', buy);// <<<<< here, you benefit from having named the click handler
    $newitem.find(".comment img").attr('src', comment ? 'img/comment.png' : 'img/comment_none.png');
    toggle("#addItemClicked");
});
```